# Operating Systems - Organization Questions

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, multicore

I am studying for a 3 topic comprehensive exam that decides If I graduate or not, and have some questions on Operating System Organization

> A) How does a multicore computer with shared memory differ from a distributed or a clustered system with respect to OS? Make specific reference to the OS Kernel.
>
> B) Briefly explain the difference between processes and threads
>
> C) Threads on a single core system are often handled in User mode. Explain why this is not acceptable on a multicore computer
>
> D) Explain at least 2 ways that the OS can handle threads on am ulticore computer

Here are my attempted answers.

A) Multicore is a single processor, which has multiple processors that work together to speed up the processing power, however since they share memory, the kernel already know the state of each other. Distributed and clustered systems use message passing, and must always alert the other kernel  what the other is doing.

B) processes refer to the high level heavyweight task, which can usually be broken down into smaller individual tasks (threads). Threading a single process allows for the abstraction of multiprocessing, allowing concurrent actions to take place.

C) DO not know, but my guess is the OS must properly distribute tasks in Kernel mode

D) Assign processes per core, or assign threads per core. If you assign proccess per core, the core will iterate through all the threads of the process, while the other core works on another process. If you assign threads per core, each core will work on a group of threads that relate to the same process.

Please let me know if anyone has any thing that can help my understanding, especially on OS Organization Topics.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A. How does a multi-core computer differ from a distributed or a clustered system with respect to the OS?

a. Clustered systems are typically constructed by combining multiple computers into a single system to perform a computational task distributed across the cluster. Multiprocessor systems on the other hand could be a single physical entity comprising of multiple CPUs. Clustered systems communicate via messages, while multiprocessors communicate via shared memory.

B. Briefly explain the difference between process and thread?

a. Both process and threads are independent sequences of execution. The typical difference is that threads (of the same process) run in shared memory space, while processes run in separate memory spaces.

C. Threads on a single core system are often handled in user mode. Explain why this is not acceptable on a multicore computer.

a. A multithreaded application running on a traditional single computer chip would have to interleave threads. On a multicore chip however the threads could be spread across the available cores.

D. Explain atleast 2 ways the OS can handle threads on a multicore computer

a. Data Parallelism - divides the data up against multiple cores and perform the same task on each subset of the data.
b. Task Parallelism - divides the different tasks to be performed among different cores and perform them simultaneously.